# identifier "ssize_t" is undefinedC/C++(20)

Tags: c

I'm on windows 11 system and try to implement `size_t` and `ssize_t` in C programming .

Although `size_t` is working perfectly without giving any error, but in case of `ssize_t` it gives the error "`identifier "ssize_t" is undefinedC/C++(20)`"

How to solve the problem ?

```c
ssize_t bytes_read = getline( &(input_buffer->buffer),
                              &(input_buffer->buffer_length),
                              stdin);
```

I got an solution in stack overflow where the datatype is suggested for windows system is `SSIZE_T`, but it is not working either.

Comment: Are you getting a *build* errors, or is it an warning from the editor?

Comment: [ssize_t](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man3/size_t.3type.html#:~:text=ssize_t%20Used%20for%20a%20count,%5B%2D1%2C%20SSIZE_MAX%5D.) is legit but not every compiler on earth has it yet.

Comment: The operating systems is relevant - what toolchain are you using (including version).  And you are clearly not _implementing_ `ssize_t`, merely _using_ it.  And do not randomly tag - the question has nothing to do with data bases or complex data types - deleted.

Comment: Looks like an IDE warning rather than a compiler error (the compiler would know what language was being compiled).  What happens if you actually compile it?

Answer (score 3):

`ssize_t` is not a type specified by the C standard. It is specified by POSIX.

Generally, you can use the C-standard type `ptrdiff_t` instead of `ssize_t`.

If you have some need for `ssize_t` specifically, your question should state what that is. In particular:

- Why are you using `getline`? That is also not a standard C routine, so it raises the question of whether you are using Cygwin or some other Unix-like software on Windows. If you have such software installed, then `ssize_t` should be available, and you may have some configuration issue. If you do not have such software installed, then `getline` will not be available either.
- Is the message coming from your compiler or something else in your IDE, such as the source code editor? If the latter, it may be a false positive, and you should try to compile.

Answer (score 3):

If your library provides a function `getline()` but no `ssize_t` then your `getline()` implementation is not [POSIX compliant](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and cannot be returning a `ssize_t`.

You should instead use whatever type it returns, check the documentation or the header file to determine the correct type.

`SSIZE_T` is indeed defined by the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), and will work if you include the appropriate header (e.g windows.h), but note that would be inappropriate, since clearly that is not what `getline()` appears to be returning.

That said, if this is a message issued by your editor/IDE pre-parsing your code, rather than an actual compiler error (which seems likely since it seems confused about whether this is C or C++), then it may simply be that the editor has insufficient information (header paths) to find the definition and fully parse the code.  If this is a pre-parse warning, try actually compiling the code to determine if it is real, or a false positive.